# camera coordinates and fig coordinates different on plotly dash python

Tags: python, 3d, camera, plotly-dash

[image]
Hey So as you can see in the above image I have an earth and there is a little point on the bottom right.

```py
  LAT, LON = 0, 0
  X, Y, Z = convert_to_cartesian(LAT, LON, 0)

  camz = dict(up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1),
              center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
              eye=dict(x=-X, y=-Y, z=-Z))
```

In The below code I make the graph using a list of different traces such as go.Surface for the earth and go.Scatter3d for the points. Maybe this is the reason why the coordinates are messed up?

```py
  AKA = go.Figure(data=All, layout=layout)
```

In the above code the X,Y,Z are correctly calculated by the cartesian function.
I use the above code which works except that the center (0,0,0) is the center of the graph not the coordinates (0,0,0).

I am trying to get the camera to go to a coordinate and face space from that coordinate. Facing space I think in theory will be easy but I have no idea how to do it. If anyone can help with that aswell the help will be greatly appreciated.
So I need to figure out why the center is not the coordinate center.